How to deal with a NULL in Connect By Level without the query going on forever?
I have a leases table, with start and end date of each lease. Some leases don't have an end date, and the field is NULL.
I want to generate a list of the payment dates/amounts over the duration of the lease. For the leases with an end date, I'm using CONNECT BY LEVEL \<= TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(pl.END_DATE, pl.START_DATE)+1,0).
However if I try to handle the case when the end_date is NULL, then the query goes on forever.
Sample data, lease 2 works fine and generates 13 rows, while lease 4 just goes on forever.



Lease_Id
Start_Date
End_Date




4
16/Jun/2023
NULL


2
20/May/2024
14/Jun/2025



I've tried various iterations of replacing the NULL with the current date, as an output field and in the results.
SELECT  CASE WHEN rownum = 1 THEN pl.START_DATE ELSE ADD_MONTHS(trunc(pl.START_DATE, 'mon') + pl.PAYMENT_DAY -1, rownum -1) END AS PAYMENT_DATE
         , pl.*
         , rownum AS pm_num
FROM    PM_LEASES pl  
WHERE   pl.LEASE_ID = 4
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(nvl(pl.END_DATE, trunc(sysdate)), pl.START_DATE)+1,0)

Also tried reading the Oracle documentation, however it focuses on actual hierarchies.I'm using this as a workaround for the moment, which works if the lease is a 100 payments or less
SELECT  pl.lease_id
        , CASE WHEN lvl = 1 THEN pl.first_payment_amt ELSE pl.lease_amt END AS lease_amt
        , CASE WHEN lvl = 1 THEN pl.start_date ELSE ADD_MONTHS(trunc(pl.START_DATE, 'mon') + pl.PAYMENT_DAY -1, lvl-1) END AS payment_date
FROM    pm_leases pl
LEFT JOIN (select level as lvl from dual connect by level <= 100) ON 1=1
WHERE   add_months(pl.start_date, lvl) <= nvl(pl.end_date, add_months(trunc(sysdate), 1))


From Oracle 12, you can LATERAL join to a row generator and use COALESCE(end_date, SYSDATE) to get the final day:
SELECT  CASE m.months
        WHEN 0
        THEN pl.start_date
        ELSE ADD_MONTHS(
               TRUNC(pl.start_date, 'MM') + pl.payment_date - 1,
               m.months
             )
        END AS PAYMENT_DATE,
        pl.*
FROM    PM_LEASES pl
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
          SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS months
          FROM   DUAL
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= MONTHS_BETWEEN(
                                COALESCE(pl.end_date, SYSDATE),
                                TRUNC(pl.start_date, 'MM') + pl.payment_date - 1
                              ) + 1
        ) m
-- WHERE   pl.LEASE_ID = 4

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE pm_leases (Lease_Id, Payment_date, Start_Date, End_Date) AS
SELECT 4, 12, DATE '2023-07-16', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 28, DATE '2024-05-20', DATE '2025-06-14' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



PAYMENT_DATE
LEASE_ID
PAYMENT_DATE
START_DATE
END_DATE




2023-07-16 00:00:00
4
12
2023-07-16 00:00:00
null


2023-08-12 00:00:00
4
12
2023-07-16 00:00:00
null


2023-09-12 00:00:00
4
12
2023-07-16 00:00:00
null


...
...
...
...
...


2024-04-12 00:00:00
4
12
2023-07-16 00:00:00
null


2024-05-12 00:00:00
4
12
2023-07-16 00:00:00
null


2024-06-12 00:00:00
4
12
2023-07-16 00:00:00
null


2024-05-20 00:00:00
2
28
2024-05-20 00:00:00
2025-06-14 00:00:00


2024-06-28 00:00:00
2
28
2024-05-20 00:00:00
2025-06-14 00:00:00


2024-07-28 00:00:00
2
28
2024-05-20 00:00:00
2025-06-14 00:00:00


...
...
...
...
...


2025-05-28 00:00:00
2
28
2024-05-20 00:00:00
2025-06-14 00:00:00


2024-05-20 00:00:00
1
12
2024-05-20 00:00:00
2024-06-10 00:00:00


2024-05-20 00:00:00
3
22
2024-05-20 00:00:00
2024-06-21 00:00:00



or, depending on how you want to handle payment dates that may occur in the same month as the starting month:
SELECT  GREATEST(
          ADD_MONTHS(
            TRUNC(pl.start_date - pl.payment_date + 1, 'MM')
            + pl.payment_date - 1,
            m.months
          ),
          pl.start_date
        ) AS PAYMENT_DATE,
        pl.*
FROM    PM_LEASES pl
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
          SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS months
          FROM   DUAL
          CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS(
                       TRUNC(pl.start_date - pl.payment_date + 1, 'MM')
                       + pl.payment_date - 1,
                       LEVEL - 1
                    ) <= COALESCE(pl.end_date, SYSDATE)
        ) m
--WHERE   pl.LEASE_ID = 4

Which outputs:



PAYMENT_DATE
LEASE_ID
PAYMENT_DATE
START_DATE
END_DATE




2023-07-16 00:00:00
4
12
2023-07-16 00:00:00
null


2023-08-12 00:00:00
4
12
2023-07-16 00:00:00
null


2023-09-12 00:00:00
4
12
2023-07-16 00:00:00
null


...
...
...
...
...


2024-04-12 00:00:00
4
12
2023-07-16 00:00:00
null


2024-05-12 00:00:00
4
12
2023-07-16 00:00:00
null


2024-06-12 00:00:00
4
12
2023-07-16 00:00:00
null


2024-05-20 00:00:00
2
28
2024-05-20 00:00:00
2025-06-14 00:00:00


2024-05-28 00:00:00
2
28
2024-05-20 00:00:00
2025-06-14 00:00:00


2024-06-28 00:00:00
2
28
2024-05-20 00:00:00
2025-06-14 00:00:00


...
...
...
...
...


2025-03-28 00:00:00
2
28
2024-05-20 00:00:00
2025-06-14 00:00:00


2025-04-28 00:00:00
2
28
2024-05-20 00:00:00
2025-06-14 00:00:00


2025-05-28 00:00:00
2
28
2024-05-20 00:00:00
2025-06-14 00:00:00



Note: You may need something more robust if payment_date is set to 29-31 as not all months have that many days.
fiddle

Thanks this is perfect!
Whilst there isn't that many leases and currently they are all monthly, I didn't like the idea of having a hard-coded value (100) in for the number of potential payments especially if any weekly lease gets created.
The tenants can only select a payment day between 1 and 28 for the same reason of variable month lengths.

You could use a case when in your connect by, so if End_Date is null, then you check whether the payment date is greater or equal with Start_Date, and, otherwise you would check for prices otherwise.
Of course, you can enhance your logical expression to have the form of
(A AND X) OR (NOT A AND Y)

if case-when is not an option for your scenario.
